# How to get error message from an AJAX call?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an jQuery AJAX call that looks as follows:

```
$.get(url, { tripName: tripName, userRowId: userRowId }, function (data) {
    $("#partialView").html(data);
}).success(function () {
    UpdateCount();
    $("#LocationList").focus();
}).fail(function (error) {
    alertify.alert("Call to get sightings failed: " + error);
});
```

The .get calls a C# controller method. I've got the C# method set up to throw a divide by zero exception for testing purposes. How do I trap the exception message coming from the C# method? What I have above isn't working (the fail method gets called but no message is being displayed) This isn't surprising because I just took a stab at it.

My C# method looks as follows:

```
try
{
    int a = 0, b = 10, c;

    c = b / a;
}
catch (System.Exception exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

Comment: It isn't working? In theory, if the exception is unhandled it will send a HTTP 500 error which would then follow the `fail()` callback.

Comment: paste your c# method code

Comment: I've pasted my C# method, and updated my question to clarify that the fail method is getting called but I'm not able to display the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
alertify.alert("Call to get sightings failed: " + error);
```

to this:

```
alertify.alert("Call to get sightings failed: " + error.responseText);
```

---

If you could set a `console.log(error)` there you can see your error message is hold by `responseText` so that should get you with `error.responseText`.

Comment: Actually, not so perfectly. It does actually get the entire response text. All 1K bytes of it! Is there some way I can just return a simple message, instead of the whole .NET error stack?

Comment: @RandyMinder i am not well versed with .NET but you can return a string in case of error.

Comment: `throw (new TempIsZeroException("Zero Temperature found"));` something like this : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_exception_handling.htm